# Passing ListView.builder index data to a text widget

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

So what I'm trying to achieve is, with the use of `ListView.builder`, when a user taps on a specific `ListTile` item, it will open an `AlertDialog` form where at the top of that form, I want to display a  `Text` widget which will show the specific index (In this case, the `String eventName` inside the `eventList list`) of `ListView.builder`.

The problem is, I have no idea how to call that index to a text widget outside of `ListView.builder`.
Is what I'm trying to achieve possible or is there another way to do this?
Also if it helps, I'm getting an error "Undefined name 'index'" when I try to pass the index inside the text widget.

More info on what I'm trying to achieve (excuse my handwriting):
[The AlertDialog Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnefm.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smc_app/Models/events.dart';

class EventsConfirmation extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventsConfirmation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventsConfirmationState createState() => _EventsConfirmationState();
}
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 List<EventList> schoolEvents = [
   EventList(eventName: 'SMC General Assembly', location: 'College Gym', time: '9AM-11AM',),
   EventList(eventName: 'College Finals Week', location: 'SMC', time: 'ALL DAY',),
   EventList(eventName: 'College Baccalaureate and Graduation Day', location: 'TBA', time: 'TBA',),
   EventList(eventName: 'Semester Break', location: 'N/A', time: 'N/A',),
];

    class _EventsConfirmationState extends State<EventsConfirmation> {
    
    
      Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context) async {
        return await showDialog(context: context,
            builder: (context){
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Form(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(schoolEvents[index].eventName), //HERE IS WHERE I'M HAVING PROBLEMS 
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'This field is required' : null,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Name/Student ID"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
          });
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Upcoming Events, Confirm Your Attendance.'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: schoolEvents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0, horizontal: 4.0),
                  child: Card(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: ListTile(
                        onTap: () async {
                          await showInformationDialog(context);
                        },
                        title: Text(schoolEvents[index].eventName),
                        subtitle: Text(schoolEvents[index].location),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

The class for EventList:

```
class EventList {

String eventName;
String location;
String time;

EventList({required this.eventName, required this.location, required this.time});
}
```

Hope someone helps me on this thank you.

Comment: You need to pass the index to `showInformationDialog()`. Something like this would work: Change the function on top to `Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context, int index)` and onTap to `await showInformationDialog(context,index);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have some options to fix your issue:

1. Like @Uni commented you can pass the index as a parameter on your showInformationDialog:

> Future showInformationDialog(BuildContext context, int index)
> async

2. What I would do, to avoid accessing the list, is pass the schoolEvent as a paramenter instead, this way if something happens to the list after you load the screen it wouldn't affect your function, I would also remove async and await, they are not necessary in this case.

> ```
> Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context, EventList event) {
>     return showDialog(
>       context: context,
>       builder: (context) {
>         return AlertDialog(
>           content: Form(
>             child: Column(
>               children: [
>                 Text(event.eventName),
>                 TextFormField(
>                   validator: (val) => val!.isEmpty ? 'This field is required' : null,
>                   decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Name/Student ID"),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             ),
>           ),
>         );
>       },
>     );
>   }
> ```

And on the list tile:

```
ListTile(
  onTap: () async {
    await showInformationDialog(context, schoolEvents[index]);
  },
  title: Text(schoolEvents[index].eventName),
  subtitle: Text(schoolEvents[index].location),
);
```

Comment: Hii, I tried to follow your 2nd option but it's giving me an error on `Future<void> showInformationDialog(BuildContext context, SchoolEvent event) {` which states "Undefined class 'SchoolEvent'. Try changing the name to the name of an existing class, or creating a class with the name 'SchoolEvent'.", but the first option by @uni works.  Sorry i'm quite new to coding and still trying to understand the logic of it all haha

Comment: Oh my bad I used the wrong name for the Class, it should be EventList, editing it.